# skipping a file from a csv file based on the parameter

Tags: java, filehandle

I have a csv file. I am uploading it to MySQL. while uploading I have to check that all the values are present in every line.
For example:

```
    File A has
    aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd (line 1)
    eee, fff, ggg, hhh (line 2)
    iii, jjj, kkk (line 3)
    jjj, kkk, lll, mmm (line 4 )
```

in the above file 3rd line has only 3 values. requirement is that the 3rd line has to be written in separate file. other three lines have to update the table.

it should skip the 3rd line and has to write in the seperate file.

any help?

Comment: how are you "uploading" the file to mysql?

Comment: Split the file by ',' and if the length if less than a desired number (4 in this case), don't write to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
String csvFile = "file.csv";
String line;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile)); 

while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    String[] country = line.split(",");
    if(country.length == 4) {
        //Do whatever should be done
    } 
}
```

This is based on example 1 in http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

You should of course do whatever you need to modify the number of elements that exist

Comment: Btw do you also need it to write the new files during the check?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something likethis ,

```
while ((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {

           StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, delims);
           int length = st.countTokens();
           System.out.println("len " + st.countTokens());
           if (length != 4) {
               continue;
           }
           writer.write(line);// you can save all the lines with 4 words into another csv file

       }
```